# Showing bits of a string in python with a timer

Tags: python

I'm trying to sequentially show the bits of a given string in python. I can convert it to binary string but not enumerate it with a timer.

Here's a minimal example based on code I'm using:

```
import sys
string = "a"
for char in string:
    mybyte = str(bin(ord(char))[2:].zfill(8)) // convert char to 8 char length string which are char's representation in binary
    for bit in mybyte:
        sys.stdout.write(bit)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

This doesn't show each bit separated by 0.5sec but wait until all bits (8 x 0.5 = 4sec) have been processed to show them.

However if I put a new line in the lop I get an timely correct iteration but with the cost of having newlines between each bit which I don't want. I'm guessing I'm doing wrong here like not having the good approach of the problem but I'm really stuck on this so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  `sys.stdout.flush()` after each write as the stdout is buffered by default

Answer (score 1):

You might have to flush `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys
string = "a"
for char in string:
    mybyte = str(bin(ord(char))[2:].zfill(8)) // convert char to 8 char length string which are char's representation in binary
    for bit in mybyte:
        sys.stdout.write(bit)
        sys.stdout.flush()  # <-- Add this line right here
        time.sleep(0.5)

    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

For Python 3, you can just use the `end` keyword argument to `print()`:

```
import sys
string = "a"

for char in string:
    mybyte = str(bin(ord(char))[2:].zfill(8))

    for bit in mybyte:
        print(bit, end='')
        time.sleep(0.5)

    print()
```

For Python 2, you'll have to import the print function:

```
 from __future__ import print_function
```